# How to compile a javascript file as a jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I would like to be able to use the JSP servlet on my JavaScript files for i18n purposes.  Take the following JavaScript for example:

```
function you_did_it_wrong() {
    alert("<fmt:message key="you.did.it.wrong" />");
}
```

I have tried to set up the JspServlet in my web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>preprocessor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>preprocessor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I call the js file, it comes back without being processed by the servlet.

Comment: o_O Javascript have nothing to do with Java. You should write JSP servlets in Java. If you really, want to run javascript in your jsp servlets, install http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ and use it

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough.  I am not trying to use javascript syntax to write java code. I am trying to use the jsp servlet to compile and run on my js files.  I could just name my js files with the extension .jsp, and reference <script type="text/javascript" src="file.jsp" ></script>, and that will work, but I would like it to also work on files with .js.

Comment: Ah. Your config seemed to be correct. Have you restarted Apache after editing the conf? * maybe it's better to ask such questions at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Also, I suppose it's better to remove javascript tag, cause your question is rather unrelated to javascript -- it can be any other extenstion as well.

Comment: it is generally related to javascript, so I added  the tag back.

Comment: ...this may also be useful for css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bozho gave the right hint. However, I'd like to answer the *concrete* problem.

---

The given code snippet will *fail* when the `fmt` taglib is not declared in top of file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" />
```

So just ensure that it is there above in your JS file.

The JSP servlet entry looks fine, although I think I would rather have used just this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*(`jsp` is the `servlet-name` of the Tomcat's builtin `JspServlet` which you can locate in its `/conf/web.xml`)*

Comment: I just realized he has defined the jsp servlet again, rather than using the original one :) (+1). Btw, note that by doing this you are servlet-container dependend.

Comment: This works in Jetty as well.  However it does not work with google app engine sdk 1.4.0 (which uses Jetty... go figure).  Others are having problems with GAE as well: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/bf609bd95f2b6f2f.  Even though my problem isn't solved, I'll award you the points.  Bonus points if you can figure out how to do it in GAE.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I don't do GAE. As an alternative, create a JSP file with `<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" %>` in top, put the necessary JS code in there and finally include this in `<script src>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do that than serving .js files through the jsp servlet.

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698912/is-it-a-good-practice-for-a-js-file-to-rely-on-variables-declared-in-the-includi). I ended up having all variables declared in the `.js` file, and having them passed through an init method:

```
init({somgMsg: '<fmt:.../>', anotherMsg: '<fmt:... />'});
```

Comment: Thanks for you're input, but in my case I would like to externalize all javascript from my jsp's.