# Getting Struts 2 valuestack variables to JQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts2

Hello I am currently developing a web application and i want to set values to all my Combo boxes in a jsp page using values in Value stack. Here is what i have tried

Action.class

```
public class OpenEducationalProfile extends ActionSupport {

private Jobseeker jobseeker;
private List<JobseekerOl> jobseekerOl;
private List<JobseekerAl> jobseekerAl; 
private List<JobseekerUniversity> jobseekerUniversity;
......
..Getters and Setters
```

I want to set my values in jobseekerOl List to Combo boxes in Jsp Page. This is what i have tried and it doesn't retrieve values from value stack. It select all the Combo boxes properly using ID. Can anybody help?

Result.jsp

```
<script> 
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var noOfOlSubjects = 0;
            var noOfAlSubjects = 0;
            alert("#foo.mark");
            $('[id=olsubjectmark]').each(function() {
                $(this).val(<s:property value="jobseekerOl[noOfOlSubjects].mark"/>);
                noOfOlSubjects++;
            });
            $('[id=alsubjectmark]').each(function() {
                $(this).val(<s:property value="jobseekerAl[noOfAlSubjects].mark"/>);
                noOfAlSubjects++;
            });
        });          
    </script>
```

Comment: Can u see what value ur getting if u put this in alert `<s:property value="jobseekerOl[noOfOlSubjects].mark"/>` ?

Comment: Put the **noOfOlSubjects** in the following way in order to get that value of it. Try this -`<s:property value="jobseekerOl["+noOfOlSubjects+"].mark"/>` ?

Comment: tried alert(jobseekerOl[0].mark"); Alert didn't appear. Any other way to check the value? I am new to javascrip and jquery. If i used a literal instead of <s:property value="jobseekerOl[noOfOlSubjects].mark"/> it works.

Comment: tried with +noOfOlSubjects+. didn't work :( :(

Comment: Do you need comboboxes (list and editable textbox) or selectboxes (list only) ?

Comment: Isn't easier for you to make an ajax call and retrieve the values from that call? You will receive a JSON object that can be easily manipulated

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I completely misunderstood your question till now. U cannot use `<s:property/>` tags inside javascript/jQuery.

Inside your form create a combo box.

```
<s:combobox label="Job Seeker Ol" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--- Select ---" list="jobseekerOl" name="jobseekerOlSubject" />
```

If u want more info about how it works.. please refer this  [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scombobox-combo-box-example/)

Comment: *U cannot use <s:property/> tags inside javascript/jQuery* - Not true.

Comment: Sure you can, as long as (1) the JS is in a JSP file (or you process JS files as JSP) and (2) they're escaped properly and render to valid JS.

Comment: @DaveNewton could you expand "or you process JS files as JSP" ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: [How to compile a javascript file as a jsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4988409/1700321).

Comment: I want to do it without <s:combobox> tag, just with basic <select> html tag. :( how can i use <s:property/> inside javascript/jquery?